# Can we reduce the time consumed by AutodiscoverUrl in ExchangeWebsevice

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am using AutodiscoverUrl to connect to exchange server but its taking long to get connected ...Is there any way to reduce the time consumed..

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried specifying what your URL is instead of using AutoDiscover?

```
m_ExchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
m_ExchangeService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
m_ExchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://exchange.company.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

You can easily find what your specific URL would be by first debugging your application when you're auto-discovering.

However, your main point of slowness may be caused in the connection to the Exchange Server, if that's the case, you'll need to look for a solution to your connectivity issue outside of your code (maybe something to do with your security setup?).

Comment: So what exactly does autodiscover buy you if you have to pass the EWS URL anyway?

Comment: Autodiscover allows your application to not require a code release when/if you change Exchange URLs.  So if your URL changes to https://newexchangeserver.company.com/, autodiscover will work with the new server by looking up the server based on the ID passed to it.